# How does QuickPic do a semi-transparent actionbar?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, translucency

In Android KitKat there are options for

```
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/TranslucentActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
```

How do I have an app perform like QuickPic where upon scrolling the content starts to scroll beneath the action bar?

```
<FrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container" 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:clipToPadding="false"
tools:context="com.jhdev.red.MainActivity"
tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

<GridView
    android:id="@+id/grid"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:numColumns="@integer/num_columns"
     android:clipToPadding="false"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Hi Julien, have you got the solution? I'm also looking for the same.

Answer (score 2):

**For Android 3.0 and higher only**

If your minSdkVersion is set to 11 or higher, your custom theme should use Theme.Holo theme (or one of its descendants) as your parent theme. For example:

```
<resources>
    <!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
    <style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
           parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
        <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

**For Android 2.1 and higher**

If your app is using the Support Library for compatibility on devices running versions lower than Android 3.0, your custom theme should use Theme.AppCompat theme (or one of its descendants) as your parent theme. For example:

```
<resources>
    <!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
    <style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
           parent="@android:style/Theme.AppCompat">
        <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>

        <!-- Support library compatibility -->
        <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

**Specify Layout Top-margin**

When the action bar is in overlay mode, it might obscure some of your layout that should remain visible. To ensure that such items remain below the action bar at all times, add either margin or padding to the top of the view(s) using the height specified by actionBarSize. For example:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize">
    ...
</RelativeLayout>
```

If you're using the Support Library for the action bar, you need to remove the android: prefix. For example:

```
<!-- Support library compatibility -->
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize">
    ...
</RelativeLayout>
```

In this case, the ?attr/actionBarSize value without the prefix works on all versions, including Android 3.0 and higher.

**[Details](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/overlaying.html)**

**Also check out this [link](http://cyrilmottier.com/2013/05/24/pushing-the-actionbar-to-the-next-level/) for more help.**

Answer (score 1):

You need to use:

```
android:clipChildren="false"
```

on your FrameLayout

Answer (score 0):

Just set action bar's style in your app theme like this:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

    ...

    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/TransparentActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/TransparentActionBar</item>
    <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
</style>

<!--Default alpha for translucent navigation/status bar is 40% of black color-->
<color name="transparent_color">#6000</color>

<style name="TransparentActionBar" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.Solid">
    <item name="android:background">@color/transparent_color</item>
    <!--Compatibility-->
    <item name="background">@color/transparent_color</item>
</style>
```